# Better way to write a JSON file to a DB?

Tags: python, django, json, embed

Here's the scenario:
-I'm using embed.ly's oembed service to pull metadata about user submitted links (more info about that service: http://api.embed.ly/docs/oembed)
-I use this content to generate previews of content on my site
-When I submit a URL to embed.ly the service gives me back a JSON file containing the metadata
-I want to write this to a database since users will be accessing this information repeatedly on my website
-I'm using Django

I have the scritp working. Below is my code. What I don't like about it is that it hard codes the keys that are found in the JSON file. If the keys change, or are not provided on a given query, then things break. I can fix the later issue, but was curious if anyone had a different approach that would tolerate missing data or changing keys.

Here is the Python code that generates the JSON file (got this from embed.ly):

```
def submit_content(request):

import urllib
import urllib2
try:
    import json
except ImportError:
    try:
        import simplejson as json
    except ImportError:
        raise ImportError("Need a json decoder")

ACCEPTED_ARGS = ['maxwidth', 'maxheight', 'format']

def get_oembed(url, **kwargs):
    """
    Example Embedly oEmbed Function
    """
    api_url = 'http://api.embed.ly/1/oembed?'

    params = {'url':url }

    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        if key not in ACCEPTED_ARGS:
            raise ValueError("Invalid Argument %s" % key)
        params[key] = value

    oembed_call = "%s%s" % (api_url, urllib.urlencode(params))

    return json.loads(urllib2.urlopen(oembed_call).read())
```

And here is my code that writes this to the DB:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = SubmitContent(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = request.user
        content_url = form.cleaned_data['content_url']

        url_return = get_oembed(content_url)

        recordSave = ContentQueue(submitted_url=content_url)

        for key in url_return:
            if key == 'provider_url':
                recordSave.provider_url = url_return[key]
            if key == 'description':
                recordSave.description = url_return[key]
            if key == 'title':
                recordSave.title = url_return[key]
            if key == 'url':
                recordSave.content_url = url_return[key]
            if key == 'author_name':
                recordSave.author_name = url_return[key]
            if key == 'height':
                recordSave.height_px = url_return[key]
            if key == 'width':
                recordSave.width_px = url_return[key]
            if key == 'thumbnail_url':
                recordSave.thumbnail_url = url_return[key]
            if key == 'thumbnail_width':
                recordSave.thumbnail_width = url_return[key]
            if key == 'version':
                recordSave.version = 1
            if key == 'provider_name':
                recordSave.provider_name = url_return[key]
            if key == 'cache_age':
                recordSave.cache_age = url_return[key]
            if key == 'type':
                recordSave.url_type = url_return[key]
            if key == 'thumbnail_height':
                recordSave.thumbnail_height = url_return[key]
            if key == 'author_url':
                recordSave.author_url = url_return[key]

        recordSave.user = user
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the valid keys are defined in [embedly's repsonse documentation](http://api.embed.ly/docs/oembed#response) you can make your code a bit more maintaininable by specifying the list of supported response keys and your translations in one place, reducing the amount of redundant code.

For example:

```
# embed.ly keys which map 1:1 with your database record keys
RESPONSE_KEYS = set([
    'provider_url', 'description', 'title', 'author_name', 'thumbnail_url',
    'thumbnail_width', 'thumbnail_height', 'author_url'
    ])

# mapping from embed.ly's key name to your database record key
KEY_MAP = {
    'url': 'content_url',
    'width': 'width_px',
    'height': 'height_px',
    'type': 'url_type'
    }

url_return = get_oembed(content_url)
record = ContentQueue(submitted_url=content_url)
record.version = 1

# iterate over the response keys and add them to the record
for key_name in url_return.iterkeys():
    key = key_name if key_name in RESPONSE_KEYS else KEY_MAP.get(key_name)
    if key:
        record[key] = url_return[key_name]
```

Comment: Thanks! As you can probably tell, I'm new to programming. This worked great. I was even able to get this plugged into CouchDB.